# Bash - Execute background process whilst reading output

Tags: bash, background-process

I'm trying to start a process (`target_executable`) and have it run in the background. I know I could do that via `./target_executable &` but in the bash script that's running the show, I want to read the output of the process looking for a particular output. Then once the output is . found, I want to let the the script complete whilst the target process is left running in the background.

This is what I have so far but there are a number of things wrong (its not running the process in the background, and it never hits "Finished Reading" even though the ID is found):

```
echo "Starting Process..."
TARGET_ID=""
./target_executable | while read -r line || [[ "$TARGET_ID" == "" ]] ; do
    TARGET_ID=$(echo "$line" | grep -oE 'Id = [0-9A-Z]+' | grep -oE '[0-9A-Z]{10,}')

    if [ "$TARGET_ID" != "" ]
    then
        echo "Processing $line '$TARGET_ID'"
    fi
done
echo "Finished Reading..."
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a job for `coproc`. From the help:

```
coproc: coproc [NAME] command [redirections]
    Create a coprocess named NAME.

    Execute COMMAND asynchronously, with the standard output and standard
    input of the command connected via a pipe to file descriptors assigned
    to indices 0 and 1 of an array variable NAME in the executing shell.
    The default NAME is "COPROC".
```

So it would look something like:

```
echo "Starting Process..."
TARGET_ID=""
coproc (trap '' PIPE; ./target_executable < /dev/null & disown) # since it's in the bg, input won't be useful
while read -r line || [[ "$TARGET_ID" == "" ]] ; do
    TARGET_ID=$(echo "$line" | grep -oE 'Id = [0-9A-Z]+' | grep -oE '[0-9A-Z]{10,}')

    if [ "$TARGET_ID" != "" ]
    then
        echo "Processing $line '$TARGET_ID'"
        break
    fi
done <&${COPROC[0]} # redirect in from coprocess output
```

Note that bash sets up a pipe for the input/output of the coprocess, so the application must be able to handle a broken output pipe. Not all commands can. (That's why I trap `SIGPIPE` in the subshell.)

Comment: Would you not have to read the rest of the output (stdout/stderr) from the co-process (if it produces anything)? It would pause otherwise.  You can combine those `grep` invocations and get rid of `read`+`echo`, I think.

Comment: @Kusalananda I think when then script ends, the pipes will be closed (and so writes will start failing anyway). At least when I tested with a looped `echo`, my terminal started displaying `foo.sh: line 5: echo: write error: Broken pipe` after the script that started coproc ended ... and I didn't really look at what OP was doing in the loop, TBH.

Comment: So, for the background process, output has to be directed to the terminal or a file for it to continue executing properly (not a pipe).  If it produces output that is.  Unfortunately it's not clear whether the process is expected to survive only to the ed of the controlling script or longer. If it should stick around for longer, it will need to be protected from a HUP signal as well I suppose.

Comment: That background task/process needs to live indefinitely even after the script process is terminated. Also there is no definitive "end" to the background processes output, the controlling script here should just "listen" until it sees what its looking for and then continue on its own execution and let the background task continue running in a fully detached manner. Does that make sense?